# Can someone help me understand backreaction?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was reading a paper on black-hole information loss and it mentioned **backreaction**. I had never heard the word before so I googled it and was surprised to find no cohesive definition that I could understand. The best I found was this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-reaction) which gives a definition akin to "a backreaction is a field that is often used to calculate forces in quantum systems." However, it gave no *strict definition* or real *physical justification*. I was wondering if someone who understood the topic could explain them to me better, because right now they seem to me to be more like quantum epicycles than anything.

P.S. I also found [this article talking](https://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/rhett.html) about back-action in quantum measurement which used the term back-reaction once. I could't quite figure out precisely how they were related though.

Comment: A simple classical example of backreaction is the force exerted on an accelerating charged particle due to its radiation of electromagnetic waves. The waves carry off energy and momentum, so there must be a backreaction on the particle. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force).

Comment: In regards to your PS, I would characterize that article as "not mainstream physics." I would personally advise you not to worry about it for the purpose of understanding backreaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hawking radiation is usually computed in the context of *perturbation theory* (more precisely, *quantum fields on a curved spacetime*). This is an *approximation* to the full theory of quantum gravity. Backreaction refers to effects that this approximation does not capture.

In more detail...

Imagine a black hole. We can model the spacetime geometry of an eternal, non-spinning black hole with a *Schwarzschild spacetime*. The key parameter of this spacetime is the *mass* of the black hole, which is constant for an eternal black hole.

Hawking radiation is computed by considering field that "live on top" of the geometry. For example, we can consider the electromagnetic field. We can compute how electromagnetic waves propagate on a *fixed* geometry, like the Schwarzschild geometry. Hawking built his argument for the existence of Hawking radiation on the mathematics of this kind of situation (plus the general principles of quantum theory), where electromagnetic waves (or other kinds of waves) propagate on a fixed geometry.

However, Hawking radiation will carry energy away from the black hole. This means the mass of the black hole will decrease as it radiates. Because the spacetime geometry depends on the mass, this means that the spacetime geometry itself will change as Hawking radiation occurs. This effect is called *backreaction*. The approximation described in the previous paragraph cannot describe backreaction, because it assumes the electromagnetic waves travel on a *fixed* background spacetime.

Backreaction is difficult to deal with because it means that common approximations are breaking down. Therefore, often people want to try to argue in one way or another that backreaction is small enough to ignore. However, precisely because it is a nonlinear effect that goes outside of our normal approximation schemes, it can also lead to some very interesting effects. In the case of Hawking radiation, backreaction leads to the evaporation of the black hole, as the mass continues to decrease, presumably to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you decompose a dynamical system into two subsystems $A$ and $B$, the equations of motion are generally going to look like
$$T_A + T_B + I_{AB} = 0$$ where $T_A$ is the equation of motion of $A$ if $B$ didn't exist, similarly for $T_B$, and $I_{AB}$ is a new term coupling the two systems. It is often reasonable to put subsystem B "on rails", meaning you fix some specified trajectory for $B$. Then the equations of motion reduce to $T_A + I_{AB} = 0$ where $I_{AB}$ has the specified evolution of $B$ substituted in. For example, you can have some large background electromagnetic field which you can hold as static, and study the evolution of point charges in this field.

However, the true equations of motion are such that the configuration of one subsystem always impacts the dynamics of the other system, which in turn impacts the evolution of the first system. For instance, this subsystem of point charges generate electromagnetic fields of their own, which will act on the sources of the ambient magnetic field, which in turm impacts the force felt by the charges. These effects are what are known as "backreactions", and are generally substantially more complicated to deal with compared to the simpler problems where a subsystem is on rails.